# Module Not Found MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql-python

import pandas
import sqlalchemy
eng = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql://root:@localhost:3306/xyz')

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\dinka\anaconda3\Microsoft VS Code\login-sys\main.py", line 3, in 
eng = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql://root:@localhost:3306/xyz')
File "C:\Users\dinka\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine_*init*_.py", line 500, in create_engine
return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\dinka\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 87, in create
dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
File "C:\Users\dinka\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\mysql\mysqldb.py", line 118, in dbapi
return **import**("MySQLdb")
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem and postiong it so that noone else could face this
write this on ur terminal or cmd

pip install pipwin
pipwin install mysqlclients

then run it

It should work